# Flutter GridView.builder align item after filter

Tags: flutter, dart

How align item on top (bottom search field) after filter data in GridView.builder?

Below is my example:

```
Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: widget.emps.length,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount:
              MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 4,
              mainAxisSpacing: 20,
              crossAxisSpacing: 20,
              childAspectRatio: 0.693,
            ),
              itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                return widget.emps[index].ename.contains(searchString) ? EmpCard(
                  emp: widget.emps[index],
                  press:  () {
                  },
                ):Container();
              }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add your code, please?

Comment: @SalihCan Yes, Tnx

Comment: more better if you give example code. You can this https://dartpad.dev/

Comment: `crossAxisCount: widget.emps.length == 1 ? 1 :
              MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 4,`

Comment: @novol Not help me....

Comment: also try add `Center` widget as parent of `GridView`

Comment: @novol Again not working....

Comment: You need to add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` in the `Column` widget.

Comment: @SaugatJonchhen Blank space is Container() @ Ruchit  is below explain. Not helped crossAxisAlignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is `no issue in alignment`, issue is you are displaying `container()` instead  of `EmpCard()` when you are not find a match,
you have to first create list for `search` outside of `GridView.builder()` and that has to be displayed. then alignment issue will be automatically solved.

update-

```
take new list out side build method;
List search=[];

//-----
onUpdate(value){
searchString=value;
search=[];
for(int i=0;i<widget.emp.lenght;i++)
{
   if(<--Your search condition-->){
     search.add(<--add your widgets here-->)}
   }
}
```

then create your `GridView.builder()` with this `search` list istead of widget.emps.

Comment: Hi,  I don't know how create  list for search outside of GridView.builder()   here is all code  before gridView is text search field https://ibb.co/5G0DLRw